# deleted camera app on rooted htc m8 kitkat

Tags: camera, htc

my htc one m8 was is rooted nd i accidently deleted my camera app using device control app nd now when i downloaded it's apk from internet it does not get installed showing message 'there was a problem in parsing the package' now how could i get back the original htc corporation camera app for kitkat in my phone.....,play store is having the app but supports lollipop nd above versions....... nd i also tried getting it from share it from other htc m8 (kitkat) showing the same message

Answer (score 0):

Just flash the stock RUU. Depending on your CID (Carrier ID), go [here](http://androidruu.com/?developer=M8) to find the RUU  appropriate for your phone's CID.

To check your CID, boot in bootloader (Fastboot) and tape `fastboot getvar cid` or `fastboot oem readcid`. You'll get something like *HTC_044* then go [here](http://www.gsmlover.com/htc-of-android-os/182358-htc-model-cid-list.html) to find from which carrier it belongs.

***Flashing the RUU will clear your phone storage, you'll lose all data (photos, apps, videos, etc).***

Answer (score 0):

You can try LuckyPatcher with the Android patch to disable signature checks on Apps, hope that works